# 404 Not Found Ubuntu LAMP

Tags: php, apache2, phalcon, lamp

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. Поставил LAMP под Ubuntu 14.10. Включил mod_rewrite указал директории в конфиге, сделал открытый доступ к папке var/www/html. Работаю с фреймворком phalcon.
indexAction обрабатывается нормально, но когда перехожу на другой action выходит ошибка 404, имеется дркгой проект на чистом php отображается первая страница но при переходе на другую ничего не выводится, пустая страница, что может быть?
в корневой директории

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

В каталоге `public`

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Если грубо, то при пустой строке запроса Apache загружает index.php, иначе пыатается искать заданный документ. Вам нужно задать правила перенаправления для `mod_rewrite` в файле `.htaccess`.

Comment: У меня есть правила для перенаправления. Проект на phalcon первый туториал, все по нему делел для проверки, не работает, только index отображается. Уже все перепробовал не мгу понять в чем проблема в linuxe сам начинающий, но сдуру снес винду и все проекты перенес на linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все я решил проблему, если у кого еще будет проблема такая: добавил `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` перед `RewriteEngine On`.